# addOval for Path seems to be undefined in flutter despite that it should exist

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make a simple circular area on a map, using

```
final Path path = Path()..addOval();
```

but for some reason I am hit with "The method 'addOval' isn't defined for the type 'Path'." despite that I've seen plenty of examples with addOval being used like this. Any idea why or how to fix it?

here is the full class that gives error:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart';

class CircleRevealPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final LatLng center;
  final double radius;
  final GlobalKey mapKey;

  CircleRevealPainter({
    required this.center,
    required this.radius,
    required this.mapKey,
  });

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    // Get the RenderBox for the map using the RepaintBoundary key
    final RenderBox mapBox =
        mapKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;

    // Convert the center coordinates from LatLng to screen coordinates
    final centerOffset = mapBox.localToGlobal(mapBox.size.center(Offset(0, 0)));

    // Calculate the radius in screen coordinates
    final radiusInPixels = radius / (size.width / 2.0) * size.width;

    // Create a circular clear area inside the circle
    final clearPaint = Paint()..color = Colors.transparent;

    // Create a circular darkened or blurred area outside the circle
    final darkPaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7) // Semi-transparent black color
      ..blendMode = BlendMode.dstOut; // Darken or blur blend mode

    // Create a path for the circular area
    final Path path = Path()
      ..addOval(Rect.fromCircle(center: centerOffset, radius: radiusInPixels));

    // Draw the circular areas on the canvas
    canvas.drawPath(path, clearPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(path, darkPaint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: what file do you see if you Ctrl- click on `Path` in your code? I mean what package does it belong to?

Comment: Path.dart ... shit, its from latLong not material! How do I make it use material Path instead?

Comment: `import something as alias` and then `alias.Path()..addOval()` of course `sonething` and `alias` needs to be changed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright so the issue was that both imports has their own Path(). Simply using prefix as `import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart' as ll;` and then using prefix when required fixed this issue.